# listview persistent insert value

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

"I have a ListView with items to edit and an insert.

The insert item template has several text boxes however I would like to make one of the textboxes readonly and keep a value in it that will persist after every insert.

```
<InsertItemTemplate>
<tr style="">
<td>
    <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
    <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel"  Text="Clear" />
</td>
<td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="tc_dateTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("tc_date") %>' />
</td>
<td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="tc_costTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("tc_cost") %>' />
</td>
<td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="tc_typeTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("tc_type") %>' />
</td>
<td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="tc_commentTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("tc_comment") %>' />
</td>
<td> &nbsp;</td>
<td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="tc_t_idTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("tc_t_id") %>' Width="15" ReadOnly="true"  />
</td>
</tr>
</InsertItemTemplate>
```

tc_t_idTextBox is the one that I made readonly and would like that to be the box that keeps the same value on every insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how to fix my issue.
My work around was to add a hidden field to the page.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="h_tc_t_id_holder" Value="0" runat="server" />
```

in code behind I set the value to the hidden field.

```
h_tc_t_id_holder.Value = App_id;
```

In the list view i add

```
OnPreRender="ListView1_OnPreRender"
```

And in codebehind

```
protected void ListView1_OnPreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    ListView1.DataBind();
    ((TextBox)ListView1.InsertItem.FindControl("tc_t_idTextBox")).Text = h_tc_t_id_holder.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to make a TextBox readonly you will need to set the ReadOnly=true

example:

```
<asp:TextBox ReadOnly="True"...
```

Comment: He's already doing that but honestly, I don't understand what is the problem he's facing :/